# How to use EMail traffic via tor

Tags: anonymity

I want to use via tor an anonymus email traffic. What I have to do? or install?

Thanks for an answer

Regards

Comment: please specify your "anonymous email" task in more details - it's a *very* broad area in general. I'll be glad to help you further!

Comment: i think what you mean is that you want to use an "encrypted email service provider" such as proton mail via tor as opposed to yahoo or Hotmail.... going on this assumption, the you don't have to do anything as tor is in an encrypted environment and when you log on to your email service provider ( encrypted)!! thus safety is assured! or should i say " security" is assured..